# Summarize with a function that returns multiple values in a list

Tags: r, summarize

I have a function that receives two vectors and returns a list of parameters, similar to this one:

```
f <- function(x, n) {
    mu <- sum(x)/sum(n)
    max <- max(x/n)
    min <- min(x/n)
    return(list(mu = mu, max = max, min = min))
}
```

Now, I want to apply that function to a grouped dataframe and get back a new data frame with columns for `mu`, `max`, `min` and the grouping variable `level`.

I have tried to do it with `summarize` as follows:

```
data %>% group_by(level) %>% summarize(p=f(x=x, n=n))
```

But instead of a dataframe with fourth columns I get one with two columns, where the second one contains an entry for every parameter coming out for the function wrapped as one-element lists.

I can process that data frame to generate one in the format I want as follows:

```
data2 %>%
  transmute(level=level, col=names(p), value=p[[1]]) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=col, values_from=value)
```

But that looks quite convoluted and ugly, so, is there any simpler way to do it?

**Update**: Complete code:

```
n <- sample(100, size=10, replace=TRUE)
x <- rbinom(100, n, 0.5)
level <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 100, replace=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(level=level, x=x, n=n)

f <- function(x, n) {
    mu <- sum(x)/sum(n)
    max <- max(x/n)
    min <- min(x/n)
    return(list(mu = mu, max = max, min = min))
}

data2 <- data %>% group_by(level) %>% summarize(p=f(x=x, n=n))

data3 <- data2 %>%
    transmute(level=level, col=names(p), value=p[[1]]) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from=col, values_from=value)
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal subset of `data` or `data2`?

Comment: @markus, I have added that. Anyway, the response by det below, is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that by replacing `return(list(mu = mu, max = max, min = min))` with `return(tibble(mu = mu, max = max, min = min))` in your function `f` and using it like this:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(f(x, y))
```

where `group` is grouping variable, `x` and `y` are variables to be used in function `f`.